# Do modern web applications need warning states?

Tags: usability, web-app, status, errors

I'm just curious about the system status in the modern web app design. In some old windows applications, they have warning(yellow colored), error(red colored) and success (green colored). In the modern web design, I haven't seen any warning status been used explicitly (except some dialog). So I was wondering if the warning status still make sense today? If no, what can be done to minimize the warning if such application goes to web? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Applications should try to resolve the situation, instead of simply sharing their worry with a customer.

**4 Things That Oracle Did Wrong**

1. In our example, Oracle uses such a bright colors to call attention for a completed task.

[image]

*Completed is too bright*

Anything "completed" is fine. You don't need to shout about it. People have other things to do.

2. A warning can possibly be better handled. I don't know what happened in this case, but in most cases, it can be eliminated with some extra code (sometimes too much code though).
3. The warning should be better explained.

[image]

*Warning what? What happened?*

Instead of writing "Warning", Oracle had enough space in that cell to explain what actually happened. Examples:

- Queued
- Timeout
- Empty dataset

  4. The text file should come to the point.

[image]
*The reason for the warning is nowhere in sight*

Back to your question:

- Warnings should be eliminated whenever possible.
- When warnings are
  inevitable, the status should tell what happened, not just "warning"
- Nothing wrong with yellow color.